# How to get AVG of a column only if the all the row values for this specific column are not equal -1?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, backend

How to get AVG of a column only if the all the row values for this specific column are not equal -1 ?

I have a table with a column named quarter, Its value can be 0-100.
But in case when this quarter data was never initiated, I keep this column value  to -1.

I need to get the average of this column data.
But if all the rows value for this column value is -1, then the average  should remain -1, otherwise just get the average of column quarter with non -1 row values and excluding the rows with some -1 values.

Note : if not all the rows value is -1, meaning some rows with -1 value and some with greater than 0 then -1 rows will be ignored to get the respective average value of this column.

I have tried something like this for now :

```
 SELECT
  sum(case when QARTER = -1 then 0 else Q1 end) as QUARTER_VALUE
 FROM TABLE yearData
```

UPDATE :

1. I get result somethings like this :

   [image: data result]
2. I want to get average of the column when all the values are not -1, but if there are -1 values with non -1 values, then ignore all the rows with -1 values to get the average.
3. If all the column values are -1 then keep the average as -1

Please guide me and help. Thank you :)

Comment: @JonasMetzler thank you very much for your insights. I have updated my question, hopefully  it will clear the question a bit more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original question (treat -1 as 0 when averaging, unless all rows are -1):

```
case
    when max(quarter)=-1 then -1
    else avg(greatest(quarter,0))
end
```

If all rows have -1, then their max is -1 and it returns -1. Otherwise it takes the average, but using 0 for rows with a value of -1.

Revised question (skip -1 when averaging, but still return -1 if all rows are -1):

```
coalesce(avg(nullif(quarter,-1)),-1)
```

Treat -1 as null when averaging; averaging skips null values.  If the average is null, all rows were -1 so use -1.

Comment: Simple and clean. I had the same idea, but was using SUM(quarter = -1) = SUM(true) which is unnecessary here. Your max idea should be sufficient.

Comment: @JonasMetzler  To get the average, Can i ignore the rows with -1 value, when all the rows are not -1 with some non -1 values ? But if all the rows are -1 values then average as -1 itself.  How to do it if possible? plz

Comment: @LaReyna that's exactly what this answer does.  if all rows have -1, then their max is -1 and it returns -1.  otherwise it takes the average, but using 0 for rows with a value of -1.

Comment: @ysth Thank you for replying :) Just realized that the client want me not to include the -1 values at all  while calculating the average, so instead of setting -1 values to 0.. the requirement is to skip that column value and get the average. I can not skip the whole row, because the next 3 columns have some data.  and yes if all the values are -1, then average will continue to be -1

Comment: @LaReyna then that's much much easier; updated my answer

Comment: wow very interesting solution :) I have already accepted answer from someone but this answer is sophisticated but still easier.. so I will rise it up to an accepted solution  :D

Answer (score 2):

Update your try slightly:

```
SELECT
 COALESCE(Avg(case when QUARTER <> -1 then QUARTER end), -1) as QUARTER_VALUE
FROM TABLE yearData
```

Avg function will not include null values, so case function turns -1 to null first, then average it all, then check fix null result to be -1 with coalesce.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution :

```
SELECT
 case  when max(QUARTER) = -1 then -1   else avg(case when QUARTER = -1 then null else QUARTER end) end as result_col
from yourTable
```

this will do the following things :

1. Will keep the average to -1 if all the values are -1 for the qwuarter columns
2. will ignore the rows with value -1 to get the average in case there are some  non -1 values too
   (because null values are not included in the average result, so they are skipped)

Hope it works for you!
(Also credit goes to JonasMetzler and ysth for good answers near to your problem  solution)

Comment: Thank you so much, this code works perfectly, what i needed to get  :D... also thank you so much to  JonasMetzler and ysth :)

Comment: updated my answer to use a much simpler solution for the revised question

Comment: @ysth Oh I see what you did there.. better indeed